# How could I append a coordinate value to an array of coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, append, coordinates

I am trying to append a coordinate to an array of coordinates.

But I am getting this:

```
 [array([637, 257]), array([[114, 233], [114, 163]])]
```

Instead of:

```
[[637, 257], [114, 233], [114, 163]]
```

I am using np.append to append the single coordinate to the array of coordinates.
What am I missing here?

```
import numpy as np 
coord = [(637, 257)]
coordinates = np.genfromtxt('Coordinates.csv', dtype =int, delimiter = ",")
coord.append(coordinates)
print(coord)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well by appending, you add a *single* element to the list. But the `coordinates` are a 2d array (an array where each row is a coordinate, so an *n× 2* array).

You can use `.extend(..)` or `+=` to add an iterable of elements (the rows):

```
import numpy as np 
coord = [(637, 257)]
coordinates = np.genfromtxt('Coordinates.csv', dtype =int, delimiter = ",")
coord += coordinates
print(coord)
```

Now we get a list containing three elements: one 2-list, and 2 `array`s. In case you want to convert the coordinates to lists as well, we can perform a `map`ping:

```
import numpy as np 
coord = [(637, 257)]
coordinates = np.genfromtxt('Coordinates.csv', dtype =int, delimiter = ",")
coord += map(list, coordinates)
print(coord)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Willem, that helped me!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `coord.extend(coordinates)` instead of `append`. Append just adds the whole list as a single element, while `extend` concatenates the new list to the old one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was a useful tip! :)